# How to detect windows8.1 start menu?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

When we press start menu on windows 8.1 it show up all new start menu with apps in form of tiles. This menu shows up on entire screen. Is there a way to detect if this menu is open in c++. Is there a winAPI to do so in 8.1 SDK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's hardly ever a reason to know. In general, an application is interested in foreground activation messages only, and doesn't care, which application is responsible (although the [WM_ACTIVATEAPP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632614.aspx)'s *lParam* provides this information). Why do you have to know?

Answer (score 2):

Call CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AppVisibility,...) to get the object that implements [IAppVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj554119) then call IAppVisibility::[IsLauncherVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj554125(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if the start menu is visible.

This is demonstrated in the [Start screen visibility sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Start-screen-visibility-b1a72059)

Comment: i provided a C snippet above but i think this is the best answer for C++, in C programming is possible to use COM objects but is a little bit complicated (too much work)

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about whether there exists a dedicated WinAPI call, but what you could do is run [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) with the start menu open and closed to determine the window handle and then examine its class and other parameters - that way if you know how to identify it you can always perform the same logic in your program - enumerate the windows, find the handle of the start menu, check if it is visible.

Comment: The windows 8.1 start menu/ launcher is not listed in windows found through EnumWindows.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use hook, a special hook for shell https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, then on `HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED` event check for the ClassName of the returned `GetForegroundWindow()`

Comment: there is no better idea but the one of @Rob Caplan - MSFT. downvoting someone with no comment can not help at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @milevyo. I will try this out and let you know the result.