# Detect if the menu bar is active (Alt, F10) in Windows application

Tags: c, windows, winapi, menu

In C code, I'm listening to various key events: `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP`, `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, `WM_SYSKEYUP`, etc. Given a window handle, is it possible to know whether the menu is currently is active? (As in, the user hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, or <kbd>F10</kbd>, and the accelerator shortcuts are underlined for all the menu items.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105881/how-to-detect-windows8-1-start-menu

Comment: `WM_ENTERMENULOOP`. I don't know why you need this information, though. What problem are you trying to solve? There is probably a better way. In many years of writing many Win32 applications, I haven't had a need for this message. `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` is *far* more useful.

Comment: In our application, we have C panels nested in .NET windows.  I am neither a C expert nor a Windows expert, but we have an issue where we need to call PostMessage on WM_KEYDOWN events, otherwise menu accelerators do not work.  We want to change our code to only do this if the menu is actually active, and not call PostMessage unnecessarily.

Comment: You should be calling [`TranslateAccelerator`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080523-00/?p=22203), then, not manually generating key events.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  Sharing the information with my team.  Looks promising!