# C# How to detect if the start menu is open

Tags: c#

So I wanted to create an application that is like a Start Menu but more of an application that does the same thing as a start menu. Though I want to detect if the Start Menu is open so it would open up my application. Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks! -Mike

Comment: Not exactly a dupe (since the answer is C++), but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085746/how-to-detect-when-the-windows-start-menu-start-screen-opens

Comment: A couple of answers in C++ https://stackoverflow.com/q/33105881/495455 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/22085746/495455

Comment: --- Anyone? ---